# Detailed Last Row Finder

Tags: vba, excel

For a project I created a more detailed last row finder which looks at more than one column.

Could you provide any feed back on the code below.

```
Function lColCount(ws As Worksheet, Optional iWhichRow As Integer = 1) As Long
Dim sMaxCol As String
sMaxCol = Cells(iWhichRow, ws.Columns.Count).Address
lColCount = ws.Range(sMaxCol).End(xlToLeft).Column
Function`

Function lRowCount(ws As Worksheet, Optional iWhichCol As Integer = 1) As Long
Dim sMaxRow As String
sMaxRow = Cells(ws.Rows.Count, iWhichCol).Address
lRowCount = ws.Range(sMaxRow).End(xlUp).Row
End Function

Function Col_Letter(lngCol As Long) As String
Dim vArr
vArr = Split(Cells(1, lngCol).Address(True, False), "$")
Col_Letter = vArr(0)
End Function`

Sub findLast()
Dim LC As Long
Dim LR As Long
Dim LCa As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim arr() As Variant
'Assigns ws = sheet1
Set ws = Sheet1
'Sets LC = to the last column number of default row 1
LC = lColCount(ws)
'I counter = 1
i = 1
'Defines array as 1 to the last column number
ReDim arr(1 To LC)
'Loops untill I = Last column counter + 1
Do While i <> LC + 1
'Sets Lr to last row of the looping column i
LR = lRowCount(ws, i)
'Sets last row to arr(I) value loop
arr(i) = LR
'Adds 1 to I ready for next loop
i = i + 1
Loop
'Finds maximum value in array and uses that as last row
LR = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(arr())
'Use to check the array value in the Immediate window
Dim Res As Variant
For Each Res In arr()
Debug.Print Res
Next Res
'Col_letter function finds the letter of the column number
LCa = Col_Letter(LC)
'copies range A1 sheet1 and all data to sheet2
ws.Range("A1:" & LCa & LR).Copy Sheet2.Range("A1")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You end two functions like this -

```
End Function`
```

Which might be a typo, but it causes errors.

---

### Readability

**Indentation**

Indenting your code makes it a lot easier to follow and maintain

```
Sub findLast2()
    '<snip>
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim arr() As Variant
    Set ws = Sheet1
    LC = lColCount(ws)
    i = 1
    ReDim arr(1 To LC)
    Do While i <> LC + 1
        LR = lRowCount(ws, i)
        arr(i) = LR
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    LR = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(arr())
    Dim Res As Variant
    For Each Res In arr()
        Debug.Print Res
    Next Res
    '<snip>
End Sub
```

**Comments**

["code tell you how, comments tell you why"](http://blog.codinghorror.com/code-tells-you-how-comments-tell-you-why/). The code should speak for itself, if it needs a comment, it might need to be made more clear. If not, the comment should describe *why* you're doing something rather than *how* you're doing it. Here are a [few reasons](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/254979/125931) to avoid comments all together.

*Naming*

*Variable names* - give your variables meaningful names.

What is LC? `lastColumn`. LR? `lastRow` What is `vArr()` an array of?

Additionally, [Standard VBA naming conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1s46s4ew(v=vs.140).aspx) have `camelCase` for local variables and `PascalCase` for other variables and names.

### Structure

If possible, you should pass argument *ByVal* rather than *ByRef*.

You also declare all of your subs and functions as *Public* by default, so call them public or private to ensure it's clear

```
Public Sub FindLastRow()
Private Function ReturnColumnLetter(ByVal columnNumber As Long) As String
```

and so on.

Comment: I had a nightmare copying the into the web browser which is why ` was included. (Could not work out how to surround my code). I will take note of the other suggestions.

Comment: I figured that's what happened, which is why I mentioned it. If it doesn't compile, usually the question is closed, but in this case it was simply a typo.

Comment: Also valid to point out that, when working with rows and columns, it is always advisable to use `Long` variables instead of `Integer` and there are some not-fully-qualified cells in both `Cells(iWhichRow, ws.Columns.Count).Address` and `Cells(ws.Rows.Count, iWhichCol).Address`, which might cause some trouble in future

Comment: @VictorMoraes Yes to both. Integers - [integers are obsolete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long/26409520#26409520). According to [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa164506(v=office.10).aspx) VBA *silently* converts all integers to `long`. I just didn't address those things.

Comment: I have amended the code- I have changed it so that I can pass the WS variable and which row, so that I can call this section of code from another sub. However I can't return the Lastrow and Lastcolumn value to the Sub that is calling the above. I have a work around where I add a sheet assign the results of last row and Column to a cell and use these in the new Sub, Is their a better way to do this? should I start a new thread?

Comment: @RhysWilliams are you using a function or a sub?

Comment: I was using two sub's...... I'm an idiot, I juts need to change my find lastrow() sub into a function and use it in the same way I have used the other functions.